# Google Map Javascript API doesn't show InfoWindows in Ruby loop

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps

I'm looping through a list of sport camps and plot a marker on a Google Map for each camp. This works for me. However, when I click the marker to see the InfoWindow for each camp it only opens up on the first camp - it doesn't show when I click on any of the other markers.

Do you see what's wrong?

Javascript:

```
<script>
    function initMap() {
            var start = {lat: 43.3520209, lng: 9.9078704};

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 3,
                center: start,
                scrollwheel: false
            });

            <% @camps.each do |camp| %>
            var <%= camp.city %> = {lat: <%= camp.longitude %>, lng: <%= camp.latitude %>};

            var contentString = '<%= link_to camp.name, camp.url, target: "_blank" %>'

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString,
                maxWidth: 200,
                maxHeight: 200
            });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: <%= camp.city %>,
                map: map
            });

            <% end %>

            marker.addListener('click', function() {
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                  });
    }
  </script>
```

[image]

Comment: If I move the `marker.addListener` inside the loop then both markers start to open the InfoWindow but no matter which marker you click on, it always opens the 'Barcelona' camp one.

Comment: you're overwriting the javascript `var`s each iteration.

Comment: You are right. Not too familiar with JS at this point. Do you have any resources/an explanation on how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working answer, that I learned from this one: [How to Create InfoWindows for Multiple Markers in a For loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355249/how-to-create-infowindows-for-multiple-markers-in-a-for-loop)

```
<script>
    function initMap() {
            var start = {lat: 43.3520209, lng: 9.9078704};
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 3,
                center: start,
                scrollwheel: false
            });

            <% @camps.each do |camp| %>
            var markerLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<%= camp.longitude %>, <%= camp.latitude %>);
        var title = <%= camp.id %>
        var iwContent = '<div class="inside">'
            + '<%= image_tag(camp.image.url) %>'
            + '<br />'
            + '<br />'
            + '<%= link_to camp.name, camp.url, target: "_blank" %>'
            + '</div>'

            createMarker(markerLatlng, title, iwContent);

            function createMarker(latlon,title,iwContent) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: latlon,
              title: title,
              map: map
        });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infowindow.setContent(iwContent);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });

        }

            <% end %>

    }
  </script>
```